# SQL How to combine two tables into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the following error while trying to create a new table in SQL (Table3) using some columns from a current table (Table1) and combining with new columns from a second table (Table2): "Cannot find either column "a" or the user-defined function or aggregate "a.sum", or the name is ambiguous."

The code is the following:

```
 select a. [Quarter]
  ,a. [Source Location]     
  ,a. [Destination Location]            
  ,a. sum([Total Volume]) as 'Total Volume' 
  ,a. sum([Total Cost]) as 'Total Cost' 
  ,b. [Source_City] 
  ,b. [Source_State]    
   Into [2016].[dbo].[Table3]
   FROM [2016].[dbo].[Table1] a
  ,[2016].[dbo].[Table2] b

  Where a. [Source Location]  = b. [Source_Location]

  Group By a. [Quarter] 
  ,a. [Source Location]     
  ,a. [Destination Location]            
  ,b. [Source_City] 
  ,b. [Source_State]
```

The error is in reference to [Quarter]; however, [Quarter] is a defined column in Table 1. In addition [Source_Location] is a defined column in Table2.

Can anyone assist with how to resolve this problem and successfully combine these two tables into a third one?

Thank you for your help!

GK

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to comment on other aspects of the formatting, but the issue is your use of `sum()`.  You have:

```
 a.sum([Total Volume]) as 'Total Volume',
 a.sum([Total Cost]) as 'Total Cost'
```

The correct syntax is:

```
 sum(a.[Total Volume]) as [Total Volume],
 sum(a.[Total Cost]) as [Total Cost]
```